# Change default Code Analysis limit for cyclomatic complexity for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, static-code-analysis

Is there a way to change the default threshold for the cyclomatic complexity code analysis rule CA1502? The default value set by Microsoft is 25 but I want it to be 15. I'm trying to make the build fail with the new default cyclomatic complexity of 15 in the VSTS build pipeline.

There are a few posts already that state to use FxCop setting file but they don't show you how it's done.